# RPi B+ with WiFi clients

Tags: raspbian, wifi, raspbian-wheezy, iptables

I have my RPi B+ "working" as a Wireless Router, except for the routing part.

I can associate to the WLAN0 side of the RPi but traffic doesn't go through to the eth0 side.

Routing Table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use  Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.31.254     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.31.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

iptables (nat):

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain logdrop (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Essentially the setup is    {internet} -- {eth0} {wlan0} -- {wifi clients}

I feel like I'm missing something. Probably iptable related as I'm sort of using this to learn.

Answer (score 1):

What the issue came down to was that my DNS settings were incorrect.

Even though my dhcpd.conf contained 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 it did not match that of the gateway. Once I matched up the DNS entries in the dhcpd.conf and restarted hostapd everything worked accordingly.